# Why does the strchr not take the program into an if condition?

Tags: c, string, strchr

I am trying to run the following code, but during execution, the code does not go into the if condition. 
Why does the code not enter the if condition during runtime? I have marked the problem condition.

Running this program on Windows 10.
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)

I have tried using the ternary operator and the if statement with a different string, and strchr works fine in that case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {

    static char str[] = "hello world";
    static char inputTime[] = "12:05:10PM";
    char *result = strchr(str, 'w');
    long int tempNum = 0;
    char *token, tempStr[10], delimit[] = ":";

    if (strchr(str, 'w'))
        printf("\nFound w");
    else
        printf("\nDid not find w");

    (strchr(inputTime, 'P')) ? printf("\nTrue") : printf("\nFalse");

    token = strtok(inputTime, delimit);

    if (strchr(inputTime, 'P')) {
        printf("Found PM\n");
        tempNum = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        if (tempNum != 12) 
            tempNum += 12;
        sprintf(tempStr, "%lu", tempNum);
    }
    printf("\ntempStr: %s", tempStr);

}
```

The above code gives me this output:
C:\Users\XX\Documents\Tests\c-programming>a.exe

Found w

True

tempStr:         σ@

Comment: Edited the post to include the declaration of tempStr.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, **complete**, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code you posted won't even compile.

Comment: With `token` defined and initialized, the code works as expected.  a [mcve] is required.

Comment: So, what is `token`, please.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Added the code that will allow this snippet to compile and execute.

Comment: @alk I'm trying to get the first 2 characters of the string using the delimiter. That substring gets stored as token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strtok` function splits the given input string into tokens.  It does this by modifying the string to tokenize, placing a null byte in place of the delimiter to search for.

So after the call to `strtok`, `inputTime` looks like this:

```
{ '1','2','\0','0','5',':','1','0','P','M','\0' }
```

A null byte is put in place of the first `:`.  So if you were to print `inputTime` you would get `12`, meaning you won't find a `P`.

Because the input string is modified, you should search for `P` *before* calling `strtok`.

Comment: Thanks @dbush for the explanation! I've got the answer now.